# Representing an exponential function with Fourier series

Tags: matlab, fft, dft

I am trying to represent a double exponential function with Fourier series in Matlab, but without the dc component. The basic function has the form `K*(exp(-t.*alpha) - exp(-t.*beta))` and the expected format should be like this [double exponential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yBtT.jpg) with the time domain function. I used the Heaviside function to make the rectangular window and invert the waveform.

```
clear, clc

Tr = 1.5E-6; Tf = 50E-6;
al=1/Tf;    be=1/Tr;        % alpha and beta
f0 = 1/(8*Tf);             
T = 1/f0;                   % fundamental period
K = 1;                      % Amplitude
t=0:Tr/4:T;                 % Time 
w0 = 2*pi/T;                % Fundamental freq (in rad/s)
uV = 1E-6;                  % 1 uV = 1E-6 V


%% Double exponential - TD continuous
DEXP_TD_parameters = K* (exp(-t.*al) - exp(-t.*be));
DEXP_TD = K* (exp(-t.*al) - exp(-t.*be)).* (heaviside(t)-heaviside(t-T/2)) ...
        - K* (exp(-(t-T/2).*al) - exp(-(t-T/2).*be)).*(heaviside(t-T/2)-heaviside(t-T));
```

Then, I calculated the `ck` of the series and plotted the time domain function again.

```
%% DEXP - Fourier coefficient c_k
h = 150;      % Number of harmonics

for m = 1:h
    if mod(m,2) == 0, ck(m) = NaN; 
    else
        ck(m) = (K/pi) * ( (1+exp(-al*pi/w0)) / (1j*m+al/w0) ...
                          -(1+exp(-be*pi/w0)) / (1j*m+be/w0) );
        ck_n(h-m+1) = (K/pi) * ( (1+exp(-al*pi/w0)) / (1j*(-m)+al/w0) ...
            -(1+exp(-be*pi/w0)) / (1j*(-m)+be/w0) );
        
  
    end
end
ck_n(ck_n == 0) = NaN;


%% FD/TD Reconstruction 

DEXP_TD_rec = zeros(1,(length(t)));
summ = zeros(1,h);
    if mod(h,2) == 0
        hk=h-1;
    else hk=h;
    end
for m = 1:length(t)
    for k = 1:2:h(end)
%         DEXP_sum(k) =  (ck(k)) * (exp(1j*w0*k*t(m)) + exp(-1j*w0*k*t(m)));
        DEXP_sum(k) = 2*abs(ck(k)) * (cos(k*w0.*t(m) + angle(ck(k))));
    end
    DEXP_TD_rec(m) = sum(DEXP_sum);

end


%% Plots
figure(1)                   % TD
plot(t/uV, DEXP_TD,'r', t/uV, abs(DEXP_TD_rec),'--b')
grid
```

[The time domain Fourier series waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kdzj.jpg) (in blue) does not match the red curve, and I wonder why. The shape is okay, but the second half of the curve should be negative. Any tips on how to solve it?

Comment: I can't reproduce your script because I don't have the 'heaviside()' function, but I can see in your plot() call that in one case you're plotting the absolute vaue, and in the other not. The issue might be as simple as this.

Comment: That was a great call, many thanks! This was a plot of magnitude and angle before and I forgot to recheck those script lines.